# I can't make this JQuery slide code do what i want

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make 3 boxes that slides when you're scrolling.

I've got 2 of them working (They're next to each other) and i'm trying to make a big one beneath those 2 small ones.

I've added the slide code for the big one and it slides perfectly but the problem is, the 2 smaller ones overlap the big one. (Note: I've used the same code for all of them just with a different ID and topPadding)

Here's my full code(without css):

http://pastebin.com/c7HKqcpj

Here's how it looks like when it's not scrolled:

[When it's not scrolled!](http://i41.tinypic.com/2liwuol.png)

Then this happens:

[When it's scrolled!](http://i40.tinypic.com/2vtqu0i.png)

Comment: so what SHOULD actually happen?

Comment: What should happen is that all of the 3 box/blocks should move down when the scrollbar is scrolled WITHOUT the first 2 overlapping the third.

I've added the html now.